# Property 'forEach' does not exist on type '{}'

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, d3.js

I am working with Angular CLI and D3.js v4 and I keep getting a TypeScript error: `Property 'forEach' does not exist on type '{}'`. The error occurs on a `forEach` function when I try to bring in my data.

I am following [D3 Tips and Tricks](https://leanpub.com/d3-t-and-t-v4/read) which seems very extensive and helpful for the graphing library but unfortunately isn't helpful for my current problem.

I know the path to my json file is correct bc I can `console.log` the data if my `forEach` function is commented out in my code.

I also tried to define `data` before the `forEach` function in an effort to let Typescript know that `data` is an array.

Any help is appreciated! Thanks!

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import * as d3 from 'd3';

@Component({
    selector: 'pl-lukaku-graphs',
    templateUrl: './lukaku-graphs.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./lukaku-graphs.component.scss']
})
export class LukakuGraphsComponent implements OnInit {

    constructor() { }

    total_min() {
        // create var for graph wrap
        let wrap = document.getElementById("wrapMinPlayed");
        // set up graph area
        let margin = {top: 30, right: 20, bottom: 30, left: 20},
            width = wrap.offsetWidth - margin.left - margin.right,
            height = wrap.offsetHeight - margin.top - margin.bottom;
        let data = [];
        d3.json('../../../../assets/data/lukaku.json', function(error, data) {
            console.log(data);
            console.log(error);
            if (error) throw error;
            // format data
            data.forEach(function(d) {
                d.date = parseTime(d.date);
                d.close = +d.close;
            });
        });
    }

    ngOnInit() {
        this.total_min();
    }

}


[
    {
        "season": "16/17",
        "match_day": "1",
        "opponent": "Spurs",
        "home_away": "Home",
        "final": "1-1",
        "status": "Not in squad",
        "min_played": 0,
        "goals": 0,
        "goal_min": [],
        "assists": 0
    }
]
```

Comment: error seems self explanatory... you are working with an object not array stored in `lukaku.json`. Show us the data structure in that file

Comment: @charlietfl yes I am working with objects but they are wrapped in an array. Added a sample of what my data looks like. Sorry I apparently suck at formatting on here...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There's no way how TypeScript can be aware here that `data` is an array that has `forEach` method.

In order to fix this, `data` should be typed properly, like:

```
d3.json('../../../../assets/data/lukaku.json', function(error, data: any[]) {
  ...
})
```

Since `d3.json` is [generic method](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/8ae97451d57d987c16031938a1987b03567be701/types/d3-request/index.d.ts#L77), the right way to do this is to specify generic type:

```
d3.json<any[]>('../../../../assets/data/lukaku.json', function(error, data) {
  ...
})
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I was fairly certain the issue had something to do with the way I had typed `data` but I couldn't find a solution. Thanks again for your help!

Comment: @tripstar You're welcome. Most times a param would be implicitly typed as `any` and won't have such problem, but this case is different. That's why it is always a good idea to check type definition (in type files or IDE type suggestions).

Comment: thanks again. Was just about to jump on here and see if I could get a more in depth answer. Trying to learn as much as I can about ES6!